# Does starting too many new threads in python eventually lead to a memory leak?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I currently have a python program that makes API calls indefinitely. Each time it needs to make a new API call it starts a new thread like so:

```
Thread(target=self.make_api_call, args=(foo, bar)).start()
```

This works fine, however, after a few days of leaving the program running it always fails to create new threads and fails.

I get the following error multiple times (I assume it is for every thread that the program attempts to create and start):

```
internal buffer error : Memory allocation failed : growing buffer
```

Why is this the case? I believe all of my threads terminate after a short period of time (I don't have any reason to believe that any of the threads do not terminate). Is there a limit to the number of threads that can be created in a python program.

I have also looked into using a threadpool; will a thread pool solve my above problem? If so, how would the following logic be translated into a threadpool?

```
        threads = []

        for call in range(1, call + 1):
            t = Thread(target=self.make_api_call, args=(foo, bar, call))
            threads.append(t)

        for thread in threads:
            thread.start()

        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Releasing Memory After Threads End](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50031691/releasing-memory-after-threads-end) - *"Without a concrete example of what your API and worker processes/threads are doing its hard to provide a specific answer."*

Comment: I don't see why this would leak, but yes, thread pools (`from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool`) should be preferred when possible. Threads are expensive to create/destroy, so it's best to re-use threads when you're just running jobs.